# Downloading data in MemoryStream

Tags: blazor

I have a google table and download it:

```
 Task<byte[]> _res = Http.GetByteArrayAsync(_webPath);
```

Then I make a Stream:

```
Stream _stream = new MemoryStream(_res.Result);
```

And work with this stream.
I want to parse table.
In console .net core application this method work good, but when i use it in blazor app, it doesn't work.

```
Task<byte[]> _res = Http.GetByteArrayAsync(_webPath);
Console.WriteLine("3");
_stream = new MemoryStream(_res.Result);
Console.WriteLine("4");
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf24G.png)

I haven't exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `_res.Result` blocks the thread until the task is completed which results in a deadlock as blazor only has one thread.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result?view=netframework-4.7.2

> Accessing the property's get accessor blocks the calling thread until the asynchronous operation is complete; it is equivalent to calling the Wait method.

You need to await the task with `await _res` so that the thread isn't block and can complete the task.